# Can't find Office Web Apps 2010 to download

Tags: office-web-apps

I need to install on-premise office web apps 2010 but I can't find the location to download it from.
Everywhere I look point to the Volume Licensing Service Center but when I log in I can't find it there.
My workplace has license for Office 2010 but I still can't find Web Apps anywhere.

Comment: Do you remember to go to the Office Professional Plus 2010 32-bit or Office Standard 2010 32-bit page. Even though you want to download some 64-bit stuff it should be hidden on the 32-bit pages.

Comment: Looks like what I need. Thanks. If you write it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you remember to go to the Office Professional Plus 2010 32-bit or Office Standard 2010 32-bit page.
Even though you want to download some 64-bit stuff it should be hidden on the 32-bit pages

Comment: just to be clear - on the Office Professional Plus 2010 32-bit page I get only the web apps 2010 64bit installation and the office professional 32bit installation. I don't see web apps 32bit version which I need. Should I install the complete office pack? Actually I already did but I still can't find the office web apps functionality on my sharepoint installation.

Comment: The web apps are a serverside install and only exist in a 64 bit version. That all you need